# How to add an animated loader to XCode project with Swift?

Tags: swift, animation, uiviewanimation

My task is to add loader with animation to the project written in Swift. Designer said what l need to tell him in what format he needs to send me this loader, and my goal will be to add this loader to the project.

Maybe you can share some information about adding loaders with animation to the project? I found some info about creating animated loaders by hands, but in our project designer had already been created this loader, l just need to export it to the project and l really have no idea, how to do it right.

Thank you so much for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a gif as a loader or use [lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-ios) if you have a json file representing the loader